# too much recursion error in jQuery when trigger the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to trigger the unchecked checkbox, so I tried lot with help of Google, still I can't find a solution,

**Attempt 1:**

```
jQuery(".checkbox").attr("checked", false).trigger("click");
```

When using attempt 1, no changes in my OP,

**Attempt 2:**

```
jQuery(".checkbox:checkbox").each(function() {
    var code = jQuery(this).val();
    var all_list = jQuery("#all_listings").val().split(",");

    if (jQuery.inArray(code,all_list) >= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        jQuery(this).trigger("click");
    }
});
```

using attempt 2 returns a error `too much recursion`

So how to avoid this error? or how to trigger the unchecked checkbox?

Thanks!

**Solved:**
problem solved with help of `@praveen kumar` and `attempt 2` I changed the if else, now `too much recursion` solved.

```
jQuery(".checkbox:checkbox").each(function() {
        var code = jQuery(this).val();
        var all_list = jQuery("#all_listings").val().split(",");
        if(jQuery.inArray(code,all_list) == -1){
           jQuery(this).trigger("click");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like an A-B problem. Can you describe what you're trying to achieve, instead of the problem you have.

Comment: `jQuery(this).trigger("click");` in attempt two this line is your recursion problem. Recursion just means it loops back on it self and restarts the cycle. Somehow it never executes your `if` statement. And I agree with @RoryMcCrossan this is not very clear to me either.

Comment: @roy I have one hidden input field is #all_listings, it has value like 10,12 now I want to trigger the other checkbox except 10,12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can completely change your **Second Attempt** to this way:

```
jQuery(".checkbox:checkbox:not(:checked)").trigger("click");
```

Hope this helps!

---

You need to use this way:

```
jQuery(".checkbox").filter(function () {
  return (jQuery(this).prop("checked") == false);
}).trigger("click");
```

Or you can use:

```
jQuery(".checkbox").filter(function () {
  return (this.checked == false);
}).trigger("click");
```

Or much simpler:

```
$('.checkbox:not(:checked)').trigger("click");
```

Comment: Why not just `return !this.checked`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Don't say you can also give `!this.checked`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Or why not just using `$('.checkbox:not(:checked)')`?

Comment: @praveen in your answer is correct but my self no change, can you edit my second attempt?

Comment: @praveen I have one hidden input field is #all_listings, it has value like 10,12 now I want to trigger the other checkbox except 10,12